# muting alerts for microservices which are not reason for cause

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I've 3 microservices(A,B,C) running in k8s, we are using prometheus for monitoring and alerting if something goes wrong.

in my case **Service A** calls **Service B** intern **Service B** calls **Service C**, because of something went wrong **Service C** returning 5xx errors, so **B** also returns 5xx to **A**. finally **A,B,C**'s metrics looks bad in prometheus. alert manager starts firing alerts for A,B and C.

to mute alerts **A and B** which approach better?

https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#inhibit_rule ? might this help in scenario?

if yes could anyone provide example for it?